# A 64bit alternative QuickPar?

Tags: windows, software-rec, 64-bit

I've been a long time QuickPar user but it doesn't have a 64bit version, is there any good x64 QuickPar like apps out there?

Answer (score 5):

[MultiPar](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA021385/) is the next-generation of Parchive (PAR3 file format) to protect data.

Multipar can do file verification, error detection, correction and recovery to protect your files and folders from deletion, copy errors, download errors, software errors, hardware errors, virus infection, malicious tampering, and all other forms of data corruption.

MultiPar consists of PAR clients and a GUI to control them. Though the console applications are open source (PAR clients are GPL), the GUI application is closed source.